# Creating spock tests in runtime

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, functional-testing, spock, geb

Is there any possibility to create spock tests in runtime? I tried to create several meta-methods in a loop within a GebSpec but they are ignored during the tests execution.

Or maybe somebody could suggest any workarounds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? I can't think why you'd want to define tests at runtime

Comment: I'm going to test the multiple submission of form with different fields having values with different constraints. If I create a separate method for each case it becomes a long manuscript with a lot of repetitive code. So I thought if there is a possibility to encapsulate the boilerplate logic to some method or closure and then to compose test methods (e.g. via iterating a map) just before the tests execute?

Comment: Can't you just use a data table? https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html

Comment: I tried to avoid data tables because of some code duplication and hardcoding but it seems that I have no choise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tim mentioned, datatables are the way to go.
You don't need to duplicate code in data tables, you can make them fully dynamic.

```
@Unroll
def "Check form submit params: '#login', '#pwd'. Expected - #result"(String login, String pwd, boolean result) {
    setup:
      // do your test
    where: [login, pwd, result] << [ [ "user", "qwerty",  true], [ "user", "1234",  false] ]
}
```

Please note nested arrays in where clause. It can actually be a fully dynamic array created at runtime.
Also please notice an `@Unroll` annotation, as it will give you nice test method names.

Answer (score 0):

you can simple write loop/sql query in where clause. a test suite runs accordingly to the number of where possible.

example:

```
@Unroll
def "test suite for each student"(){
  given: ""
    .......................
  and :  ""
    .......................
  then:  ""
    ........................
  where: ""
    for (StudentList student : list){ 
      //operations
      //load the values in the variables such as there numbers or ids
 }
}
```

if the loop is true for 10 students, the suite will be executed 10 times

Comment: The problem that I need for form submission in a functional test. But anyway the seagull's answer fits.